# If value is in this list and somewhere in a column's value can I replace that column value with list value? Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, replace, python-re

There is a LOT of documentation of this yet I can not figure this out.

Here is a list I need to check if one of these values in my column values. if so, replace entire cell with list value.

```
active_crews = ["CREW #101", "CREW #102", "CREW #203", "CREW #301", "CREW #404", "CREW #501", "CREW #406", "CREW #304", "CREW #701", "CREW #702", "CREW #703", "CREW #704", "CREW #705", "CREW #706",
                "CREW #707" "CREW #708", "CREW #801", "CREW #802", "CREW #803", "CREW #805"]
```

**Example of the data i want to replace. and yes formatting has slight differences as well:**

```
Debris Crew WO# 
REFER TO IAP 12/16 TO 12/19 CREW #405
REFER TO IAP 06/02 TO 06/05 CREW #406
REFER TO IAP 03/24TO 03/27 CREW # 803
```

**Expected out put**

```
Debris Crew WO#
CREW #405
CREW #406
CREW #803
```

My issue is that I do not know how to tell python to search a column value with a the list to look for a match. and if that list value is in that column value. replace the current column value with the list value

Codes I have tried:

1)

```
df.loc[df['Debris Crew WO#'] == active_crews, 'Debris Crew WO#']
# doesn't work. This was done before research lol I get the following error, which makes sense
# ValueError: ('Lengths must match to compare', (2216,), (19,))
```

2. 

```
df.loc[:, ['Place Holder']] = df.loc[:, 'Debris Crew WO#'].str[28:]
# this code "works" but due to different formatting i get data back like this:
8   REW #406
9   CREW #406
# not very effective and can not be relied on. I hate hard coding anything.
```

3. 

```
df.loc[:, ['Place Holder']] = df.loc[:, 'Debris Crew WO#'].str[26:]
df.loc[:, ['Place Holder']] = df[['Place Holder']].str.split().join(" ")
# tried this due to I have this filter for specials characters with a for loop in a different code and yet I get this error and I have no clue why. Works on my other codes with no problems

#AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'

# even if I use .loc I get the same error:
df.loc[:, ['Place Holder']] = df.loc[:, 'Debris Crew WO#'].str[26:]
df.loc[:, ['Place Holder']] = df.loc[:, ['Place Holder']].str.split().join(" ")
#plus its still hard coding (gross)
```

4. 

Next I'm going to work with RE. I have been told it is great for a "CTRL find" style like type of filtering and is a key tool in data science. So going down that rabbit hole for the next week+ starting with the RE [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) and practice it on this problem. Will edit with updates as I progress

That said. I have been learning python for almost a full two month now. Please forgive any "noob" styles/coding just trying and experimenting so I can make my life, and others around me a whole lot better.
Any help would be apricated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Crew #405 is not in your list. and Crew #803 is formatted differently like # 803 instead of #803? Are these typos?

Comment: Yes I only gave a short snippet but everything in that list are actually in the bigger data frame. there is about 2,500 rows with info like this, and that list are the crews I need to audit as of now. If needed I'll add/takeaway from that list as need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method #1 referring to a list:

You can use [`str.extract()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with the capture group being a joined list with `join('|')`. The `|` symbol is for OR and allows you to search multiple values simultaneously for each row. Capture groups require parentheses around them which is why I add parentheses as strings before and after.

```
active_crews = ["CREW #101", "CREW #102", "CREW #203", "CREW #301", "CREW #404", "CREW #501", 
                "CREW #406", "CREW #304", "CREW #701", "CREW #702", "CREW #703", "CREW #704", 
                "CREW #705", "CREW #706", "CREW #707" "CREW #708", "CREW #801", "CREW #802", 
                "CREW #803", "CREW #805"]

df['Debris Crew WO#'] = df['Debris Crew WO#'].str.extract('(' + '|'.join(active_crews) + ')')
df

#You  can also use a formatted string like this:
df['Debris Crew WO#'] = df['Debris Crew WO#'].str.extract(f'({"|".join(active_crews)})')

Out[1]: 
  Debris Crew WO#
0             NaN
1       CREW #406
2             NaN
```

---

Method #2 Extracting based off a regex pattern and ignoring the list. A `?` after a space means that the space is optional. Instead of a `space` you can also do `\s` or `\s+` for multiple spaces. `\d+` means consecutive numbers. If there are commas in the numbers, the regex is slightly different:

```
df['Debris Crew WO#'] = df['Debris Crew WO#'].str.extract('(CREW ?# ?\d+)')

Out[2]: 
  Debris Crew WO#
0            #405
1            #406
2           # 803
```

Comment: WOW that was fast and it worked. It left out crew but who cares really. Its not for presentation but instead for my to groupby() that crew number. I always feel like I over think these things at the moment. Thank you for helping me out. and I will go loo at the extract documentation right now.

Comment: @JQTS it left out a crew because of the space. Also see my other option so that you don't  have to manually update a list if your goal is just to get all of the Crews.

Comment: YES! RE just looks so much more "clean" to me. I do not understand it at all yet, haven't started reading the documentation yet but wow again. Now I have an example to practice with at home after work.  You're the bomb . com!

Comment: `str.extract`, `str.replace`, `str.findall`, are some popular vectorized methods where you can use regex. Some of them you might need to add a flag for `regex=True`.